# ¿Cuándo pasó "lo interior" a ser "el interior"? ¿Qué motivos dio la RAE para el cambio?

Tags: gramática, historia, artículos

<sup><sub>**Nota: en esta pregunta hablo de "lo interior" porque es el ejemplo que he visto en el CORDE, pero imagino que servirá para muchas otras expresiones.**</sub></sup>

En este tiempo de búsquedas y más búsquedas en el CORDE, una expresión que me ha resultado llamativa es "lo interior":

> *Un ruido extemporáneo en lo interior de la casa les sacó de la sombría contemplación de su desgracia.*
>
> Benito Pérez Galdós, "7 de julio", 1876 (España).

Se ve que en tiempos esta fue la forma culta de referirse a "el interior". Sin embargo, en algún momento la RAE debió de cambiar la norma y hoy día en la frase mencionada usaríamos "el interior".

En Ngram [se ve muy claramente](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=el%20interior%2Clo%20interior&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cel%20interior%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bel%20interior%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BEl%20interior%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bel%20Interior%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Clo%20interior%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blo%20interior%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blo%20Interior%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLo%20interior%3B%2Cc0) este cambio reflejado, con una caída del uso de "lo interior" que comienza casi llegando a 1840, y un declive final que comienza hacia 1880, mientras que "el interior" inicia su ascenso hacia 1820:

[image: lo interior/el interior]

¿Qué argumentos se daban antiguamente para considerar "lo interior" como válido? ¿Por qué motivo cambio la RAE de parecer? ¿Cuándo se produjo exactamente el cambio en la gramática?

Comment: El neutro nunca existió con sustantivos, así que *interior* aquí debió provenir de un adjetivo nominalizado por vía del artículo neutro como es frecuente. *Lo interior de la casa* entonces sería estructura paralela con *lo importante/básico/saliente del artículo*. Estoy con el móvil, pero cuando entro *interior* como sustantivo además de adjetivo? (Y de ser masculino, quizás de *el espacio interior*)

Comment: ¿Dónde esta la evidencia de que es cosa de la RAE? Que ahora se use más comúnmente "el" que "lo" quiere decir que "lo" está mal o en desuso? No entiendo la pregunta o por lo menos no la veo sustentada. Creo que deberías explicar un poco más porque te surge la pregunta.

Comment: @DGaleano no está sustentada, es cierto. La suposición de que la RAE tuvo algo que ver es porque cuando se dan estos cambios de tendencia tan marcados es porque la RAE suele meter mano en el asunto (como cuando se cambio la preposición á por a).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No creo que la RAE tuviera nada que ver con esto; simplemente, el adjetivo *interior* se fue sustantivando, y de ahí el cambio.

Cuando decimos *el interior de la casa* estamos usando la séptima acepción del DLE (parte interior de algo), que no es sino la sustantivación directa del adjetivo; pero esta acepción no aparece hasta el año 1925; anteriormente, la palabra *interior* solo es un adjetivo, o un sustantivo con significados muy específicos. En concreto, en el diccionario de 1884 (ocho años después del texto de Galdós), el sustantivo *interior* solo tenía dos significados:

> 1. m. En los coches de tres divisiones ó cajas, la de enmedio.
> 2. pl. Entrañas.

Por tanto, al ser un adjetivo, había que usar el artículo neutro (que para muchos lingüistas es, en realidad, un pronombre). Hoy día, en cambio, el adjetivo está plenamente sustantivado y lo utilizamos con el artículo masculino, con ese sentido de *parte interior* que mencionaba antes.